# Page message show in apex page

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, class

I have a VF Page where Add button helps to add rows. If an input field value of first row matches with input field of the next or any later row's field value, system will show page message only on the latter rows.

Please find my page code here. Can someone please help? Currently it shows in all the rows.

```
<apex:pageblocktable value="{!productSegmentationlocal}" var="a1" id="pbd1" >
        <apex:column >  
            <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum + 1}"/>
            <apex:facet name="header">Action</apex:facet>
            <apex:commandLink value="Del" action="{!productDel}" rerender="pbs1">
            <apex:param name="rowToBeDeleted" value="{!rowNum}" assignTo="{!productselectedRowIndex}"></apex:param>
            </apex:commandLink>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headervalue="Baxalta Product " id="Prod">
        <apex:pagemessages id="pageMessages" ></apex:pageMessages>
          <!--  onchange="psProduct('{!rowNum}');"-->
            <apex:selectList value="{!a1.Product__c}" label="Baxalta Product" size="1" onchange="psProduct();" id="BaxaltaProductValue">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!productOptions}"></apex:selectOptions>
            </apex:selectList>
        </apex:column>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change 2 things:

1. Since you don't want the same error on each and every line, change the `apex:pagemessages` to `apex:pagemessage`. The `apex:pagemessages` is meant to show all errors that occur on a page on 1 central place. Multiple apex:pagemessages on a page will allways show the same value. `Apex:pagemessage` are individual error messages that can contain individual errors.
   See this explanation as well: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008xuuIAA
2. make the rendering of the `apex:pagemessage` dependent on a line-specific property. E.g. put a value '`errormessage`' on the elements in `productSegmentationLocal` list and add a '`rendered`' propery to the `apex:pagemessage` based on whether or not the error value is filled for that line. If productSegmentationLocal contains custom objects, you might need to wrap those in a wrapper class so you can fit in the errorMsg variable.

e.g.

```
<apex:pagemessage rendered="{!a1.errorMsg != null}" summary="{!a1.errorMsg}" severity="error" strength="3"/>
```